# Order by the nearest date in the joined table with a where condition - MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, date, join, left-join

-Hello!

### I have those 2 tables:

```
     1.events                             2.eventdates 
+------------------+         +---------------------------------------+
| id |    title    |         | id | event_id |    date    | bookable |
+------------------+         +---------------------------------------+
| 1  |   event1    |         | 1  |     1    | 2010-03-25 |     1    |
| 2  |   event2    |         | 2  |     1    | 2012-02-20 |     1    |
| 3  |   event3    |         | 3  |     2    | 2014-12-15 |     1    |
+------------------+         | 4  |     2    | 2014-10-28 |     1    | <
                             | 5  |     2    | 2014-10-24 |     0    |
                             | 6  |     3    | 2014-11-30 |     1    | <
                             | 7  |     3    | 2014-06-17 |     1    |
                             | 8  |     1    | 2014-12-25 |     0    |
                             +---------------------------------------+
```

### Objective:

The objective is to display each event by next available (ORDER BY) with:

- his next date if exists and if bookable
- empty if no corresponding result

If today is  2014-10-17 it should be something like:

```
'event2', '2014-10-28'
'event3', '2014-11-30'
'event1', '' (or NULL)
```

--

I really need that in the same query because I want to use a pagination on the events.
This is the reason I can't sort data after my query with php ...

I wasn't able to do it with a simple left join because of the WHERE `bookable` that exclude event 1 from the query.

I have also tried with subqueries but I can't manage to get the next date of each event.

--

Does someone have and idea or a query I can test to get the desired result?

All help is appreciated.

Thank you!

Comment: Paste your query and we will take it from there.

Comment: Yes, please paste your query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT e.title, d.date
  FROM events e
  LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT event_id, MIN(date) AS date
      FROM eventdates
      WHERE date >= DATE(NOW()) AND bookable = 1
      GROUP BY event_id
  ) d ON d.event_id = e.id
ORDER BY d.date
```

Or without subquery:

```
SELECT e.title, MIN(d.date) AS date
  FROM events e
  LEFT JOIN eventdates d
    ON d.event_id = e.id
   AND d.date >= DATE(NOW())
   AND d.bookable = 1
GROUP BY e.id, e.title
ORDER BY date
```

Comment: I'll take the second query,You just teach me that it's possible to add multiple condition to a join. Thank you so much @Rimas!